# Setting up BrowserSync to work with a build process and watch for changes

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to create a basic gulp build process template that starts with an app folder containing html, sass, javascript, and image files and builds those files into a public folder.  I am using gulp to watch the app folder for changes and then automatically refreshing the build process to the public folder.

I using browser-sync to serve the public folder and watch for changes but it doesn't seem to automatically reload when a change to the public folder is made.  If I manually refresh the browser the changes are reflected.

Thanks for the help, see below for my gulp file:

```
//BASIC GULP FILE SETUP
//-------------------------------------------------------------

//Include Gulp
var gulp             = require('gulp');

//General Plugins
var browserSync      = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload           = browserSync.reload;
var del              = require('del');
var watch            = require('gulp-watch');
var runSequence      = require('run-sequence');

//CSS Plugins
var sass             = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer     = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var csso             = require('gulp-csso');

//JS Plugins
var concat           = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify           = require('gulp-uglify');

//HTML Plugins
var minifyHTML       = require('gulp-minify-html');

//IMG Plugins


//-------------------------------------------------------------
//TASKS
//-------------------------------------------------------------

//Clean Public Folder
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    del(['public/**/*']);
});

//CSS Tasks
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));

});

//HTML Tasks
gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./app/**/*.html'], {
            base: 'app'
        })
    .pipe(minifyHTML())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
    ;
});

//Image Tasks
gulp.task('image', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/images'));

});

//JS Tasks
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));

});


// Watch files for changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    // Watch HTML files
    gulp.watch('./app/*.html', ['html'], browserSync.reload);
    // Watch Sass files
    gulp.watch('./app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'], browserSync.reload);
    // Watch JS files
    gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*', ['js'], browserSync.reload);
    // Watch image files
    gulp.watch('./app/img/*', ['image'], browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['watch'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./public"
        }
    });
});


gulp.task('defualt');
gulp.task('build', [], function(callback) {
  runSequence('clean',
              'sass',
              'html',
              'js',
              'image');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more poking around the forums and the browser-sync documentation. In my serve task I needed to add a watch function to the Public directory that would manually call the reload every time a change was detected. So my 'browser-sync' task, now renamed 'serve', needs to look like this:

```
//Browser Sync Server
gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./public"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch("./public/**/*").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

I am sure there is a way to do this with browser-sync's streams as well, but this manual reload method found in the docs has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in a [files](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-files) object in the `init` function so it knows what to look for. No need for a different `watch` task, Browsersync does all that for you.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['watch'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
      server: {
          baseDir: "./public"
      },
      files: [
        '**/*.css',
        '**/*.js',
        '**/*.html'
        // etc...
      ]
  });
});
```